# Why does onerror not intercept exceptions from promises and async functions

Tags: javascript, promise, onerror

I want to use onerror to intercept and log all errors that occur in my JavaScript application. This works as expected except when using promises or async functions.

In the following snipped the exception thrown by `fail` is intercepted as expected but `rejectPromise` and `throwAsync` instead of invoking the onerror handler always show an `Uncaught (in promise) Error` in the console?

How can I **always** intercept **all** errors in a code base that uses promises and async functions?

```js
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  console.log('onerror handler logging error', message);
  return true;
}

function rejectPromise() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('rejected promise'));
}

async function throwAsync() {
  throw new Error('async exception');
}

function fail() {
  throw new Error('exception');
}

rejectPromise().then(() => console.log('success'));
throwAsync();
fail();
```

Comment: for that, the Promise have a second Parameter which is the reject Function Handler which can be handled by using .catch() on the Promise. 
This implies already that a Promise use try/catch

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add a window handler for `onunhandledrejection`, since unhandled Promise rejections aren't exactly the same things as errors. Check the results of the below snippet in your *browser console* (not the snippet console, it'll have problems trying to display the big object):

```js
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  console.log('onerror handler logging error', message);
  return true;
}
window.onunhandledrejection = function(errorEvent) {
  console.log('onunhandledrejection handler logging error', errorEvent);
  return true;
}


function rejectPromise() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('rejected promise'));
}

async function throwAsync() {
  throw new Error('async exception');
}

function fail() {
  throw new Error('exception');
}

rejectPromise().then(() => console.log('success'));
throwAsync();
fail();
```

Comment: btw, i don't think the `onunhandledrejection` has the same interface as `onerror`

Answer (score 3):

You can add `addEventListener` to fix that as `throw new Exception()` will be raising an error event. So `fail()` will raise an `error` event

```
window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
   alert("Error occurred: " + e.error.message);
   return false;
})

window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function (e) {
  alert("Error occurred: " + e.reason.message);
})
```

Hope this helps !!