# How to ensure window.onerror to fire for all errors?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, onerror

I have this simple code at the start of my `ts` file

```
//window.onerror = function() {
//    alert('err')
//};

window.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
alert(event.message)
})
```

As you can see, I've tried both syntaxes.

In another function later on I have:

```
throw new Error('dummy err');
```

But the global listener does not fire

What can the issue be?

Chrome shows the the global listener to this line. but nothing happens

I am using React. Though I dont see React to be touching this

How do I ensure that all thrown errors get to my top global handler?

BTW: even regular errors, that are thrown lets say by `fetch` which get back 500 errors, are also not caught by the global handler. Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use react`ErrorBoundary https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html` to catch all errors.
Though above behaviour is weird.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I realized that the errors that were not caught were only from promises / async. I quickly found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55178672/240742